# Specific folder for each user php

Tags: php

I have to create a custom module in php,scenario is i am trying to upload user pdf documents into a separate folder for each user.For example Uploads folder-->User1 folder-->pdf1.pdf.

for an indivuidual user there should be only one folder so that user can upload multiple documents on there assigned folder.

To conclude i have a form with 2 browse buttons,when user submits a folder will create inside a default folder(Uploads) name User1 then all his 3 documents should be uploaded in User1 folder.

I can easily able to upload files on main Uploads folder but cant able to move the files to specific user folder.

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
        $errors = array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

        $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name'])));
        $extensions = array("pdf", "docx", "doc");

        if (in_array($file_ext, $extensions) === false) {
            echo "Extension not allowed, please choose a pdf,docx or doc format.";
        }
        if ($file_size > 2097152) {
            echo 'File size must be exactly 2 MB';
        }
        if (empty($errors) == true) {
            $path = 'uploads/' . $file_name;

            //mkdir($path, 0777, true);
            //$dirn=mkdir('uploads/'.$file_name,0777,true);


            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path);

            echo "Success";
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="file" name="image2">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when user created make a directory inside your uploads folder with user name....while uploading do like this...

```
$dir_path='uploads/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/' . $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you store your user IDs, could be something like:

```
$path = 'uploads/' . $_SESSION['user-id'] . '/' . $file_name;
```

Comment: but i have to create folder for each??Isn't it??

Comment: @user2451541 It depends, you don't really have to, it depends on the number of users etc. You could just keep track of which files which user owns by storing it in a nextfile or a database. You could also name each individual file accordingly to each user's user id as a prefix or something. Basically it depends on your need, if you have few users then a single folder for each user makes sense but otherwise it's something that you have to think about.

Comment: you could create the folder on submit as well with something like exec('mkdir /uploads/'.$_SESSION['username']')