# PHP create new folders for file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

Idea is to store user profile photos to file server. I have done with uploading part to static folder, but I want to make It a bit dynamic.

File name is generating in following: `$userid . '-' . round(microtime(true)) . '.jpg';`

I want to store images based on `$userid`, 1000 per folder.

So it have to check if `$userid <= 1000` and folder not exists, create new folder named `000001-100000`.

For example if `$userid = 1001` it have to check if folder not exists and create new folder with name `002001-002000` and so on.

How could I achieve it dynamically? There could be over 100 000 users, so checking in following not so best idea I think:

```
if (!file_exists('images/000001-001000')) && $userid <= 1000 {
    mkdir('images/000001-001000', 0777, true);
}
if (!file_exists('images/001001-002000')) && $userid > 1000  && $userid <= 2000 {
    mkdir('images/001001-002000', 0777, true);
}
```

p.s. this is not duplicated as marked, I need to store 1000 photos per folder, not to create specific folder for each user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specific folder for each user php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351464/specific-folder-for-each-user-php)

Comment: `if $userid = 0005` how will be the folder name?

Comment: Creating folders for 100 000 users will get messy in the server. Create a random generated string for a image and store in database as blob data for that user. It will be easy for retrieving too.

Comment: Why the complication? Is there a particular reason for not just having a single folder per user in the images directory?

Comment: don't suggest user to save the file in database .it's not good approach @VenkatLokeswar

Comment: @Shanukk this is not duplicate as you marked. I need to store 1000 photos per folder, not to create specific folder for each user.

Comment: @Infinity-ohh i am sorry

Comment: @JYoThI  Yes that's a bad idea for large size files which will exceed 2GB, In this circumstance we can use as in latest MS SQL server the filestream coloum type will be more reliable.

Comment: @hassan if user id between 1 and 1000 it should store to folder 000001-001000 and if folder exsits store to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$count = floor($userid / 1000);
$begin = ($count * 1000) + 1;
$end = ($count + 1) * 1000;
$strBegin = $begin;
$strEnd = $end;
if($begin==1){
  $strBegin = "0001";
}
if(is_dir('images/'.$strBegin.'-'.$strEnd)==false){
  mkdir('images/'.$strBegin.'-'.$strEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just generate folders once. If you can't predict which folder is last, you may generate 5-50 folder more and check it with cron; do I need to generate more folders or not?

Comment: Sounds like bad idea. How about storing pictures? It need to check if user id between 1 and 1000 and store to folder `000001-001000`, if user id between 1001 and 2000 should store to `002001-002000` and so on.

Comment: in this case you don't need to check is folder exists - no additional query to hard drive. And yes, you still have to check user_id, there is no different way

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have created recursive method to check value. Then create directory according it

```
function get_thousand_value($userid,$value_min)
{
    if($userid <= $value_min){
        $return_val = $value_min;
    }
    else
    {
        $value_min += 1000;
        $return_val =get_thousand_value($userid,$value_min);
    }
    return $return_val;
}
$value_min = 1000;
$last_val =  get_thousand_value($userid,$value_min);
$start_val = ($last_val == 1000 ? '0001' :  ($last_val - 999));
$dir_name= 'images/'.$start_val."-".$last_val;

if (!file_exists($dir_name)) {
    mkdir($dir_name, 0777, true);
}
```